# How can I install Marshmallow?

Tags: nexus-5, 6.0-marshmallow

Apparently there's this really fun flappy bird game built into Marshmallow that's even better than the one in Lollipop. I've got a Nexus 5 and really want to play it ASAP. How do I go about doing this?

[image: yay]

I'm looking for both a [Multirom](https://github.com/Tasssadar/multirom)-compatible zip and the conventional way which involves wiping your device.

How can I upgrade my Nexus 5 to the latest and greatest version of Android?

Comment: Can also be done with an emulator by installing the Android 6.0 SDK along with Marshmallow(API 23) images using the SDK manager.

Comment: Yes indeed, now you can play on your computer as well. Multiplayer is best BTW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Conventional Way

This is what you want if you have a Nexus device but you've never heard of/don't use [MultiROM](https://github.com/Tasssadar/multirom). You should have an unlocked bootloader. If you don't have this, take a look [at the useful CM guide](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_hammerhead#Unlocking_the_device) to unlock your bootloader.

Also, make sure you have adb and fastboot installed and know how to use it. [Backup any and all data beforehand](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices) (doing a nandroid backup is probably best)

1. Grab the Marshmallow factory image from [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en). The Nexus 5's codename is `hammerhead` and you're looking for the `6.0.0 (MRA58K)` [file](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/hammerhead-mra58k-factory-52364034.tgz).
2. Check the checksum of your downloaded file against the one listed on the page just to be safe. This ensures the download went smoothly and you don't accidentally flash corrupted version onto your device
3. Untar the downloaded file, extracting `recovery.img`, `bootloader.img`, `system.img`, etc.
4. Connect your phone to your computer via the microusb cable. Use `adb devices` to make sure  adb is working fine (turn Developer mode and USB debugging on first).
5. Use `adb reboot bootloader` to enter fastboot mode
6. In Linux/OSX, `cd` to the folder containing the extracted files and run `sh ./flash-all.sh` to flash everything. If you're running Windows, double-click the `flash-all.bat` file.
7. Your device should automatically reboot to your new Marshmallow system. (Note that the first boot might be agonisingly long)

## MultiROM

Here's what you want if you use MultiROM. This method has the benefit of allowing you to keep your old system and all your existing data. You can then easily switch between Marshmallow and whatever you were running previously.

You should have an unlocked bootloader and a custom recovery like [TWRP](https://twrp.me/) installed, of course.

1. Grab the MultiROM-flashable zip from [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/development/rom-android-6-0-0-mra58k-flashable-zip-t3218315#post63149046). (You may also want to grab and flash the `radio.img` if you didn't install the Developer Previews.)
2. Reboot to your custom recovery and add a new ROM in the MultiROM menu.
3. Use `adb sideload hammerhead_mra58k.zip` (or `adb push` beforehand) to transfer the zip file to your device
4. After installation, reboot and choose the Marshmallow ROM to boot into

[image: marshmallow]