# Adding stock image as secondary ROM in MultiROM

Tags: nexus-5, stock-rom, factory-image, multirom-manager

I have a Nexus 5 and root. I also use the MultiROM application. I want to create a secondary ROM from stock. However, I cannot flash factory images, hence need to make flashable zip out of it.

How do I do it? What other method is recommended?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have all the things necessary for MultiROM, i.e. modified TWRP recovery installed, MultiROM zip flashed, a custom kernel in Primary ROM having kexec-hardboot patch.

If you're unfamiliar to the terms I used or the requirement is not fulfilled, see Huey's answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/125577/96277) or find the thread relevant to your device, on XDA forum or [here](https://github.com/Tasssadar/multirom).

#### Instructions:

1. Boot into TWRP and create a full [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) backup of your current primary ROM  (my assumption is that the device is running the stock ROM).
2. On the default page of TWRP :

   - go to **Advanced → MultiROM → Add ROM**,
   - select the memory in **Install to → Next**,
   - select **Backup** → select your recent primary ROM backup → **Swipe to Confirm**,
   - after flashing completes, do the reboot and choose your new secondary ROM in the boot menu.

Done!

---

If you're running a custom ROM as primary, then take its Nandroid backup, flash the stock ROM as primary, follow my aforesaid instructions, and then restore the backup to come back to custom ROM as primary one.

Comment: There is one problem with this. 1) I am on Android 6.0 currently. But I want to flash kitkat as secondary rom. So I cannot create and restore nandroid of my current rom for that. I mean if I do flash KitKat, then it would also wipe my other roms, wouldn't it?

Comment: I've not used Android 6.0 but I did have a setup where Android 5.1 was primary ROM and I used MiUI (Android 4.4). The procedure didn't wipe the other ROMs but they got affected somehow. They remained stuck on boot animation. But it is clear that things wouldn't be wiped. Why don't you take the backup of `/data/media/multiroms` in PC and go berserk?

Comment: So do I flash KitKat normally? And it won't wipe data? I generally use toolkit to do it. I explored /data/media but there seems to be no multirom folder

Comment: Sorry, it should be `/data/media/0/multiroms`. Backup your current 6.0 and multiroms folder, flash kitkat as primary ROM, take its backup and flash it as secondary ROM. Restore the backup of 6.0. for primary and see how things work out.

Comment: Do secondary ROMs in MultiROM also need to have a kernel with the kexec patch?

Comment: @russjr08, the secondary ROMs are  not required to have a kernel with that patch. I use COS12 (comes with OnePlus One) as a secondary ROM and its kernel doesn't have that patch.